how can i give a federated user only access to view secret in secrets manager and block others
So I created this secret, test_secret-Q6dOdK, in Secretsmanager, but I am using an aws federated user which uses a role:
ProdAdmin-Prod-Role/myUsername. The issue is that when I specify the principal like this
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:af-south-1:123456789:secret:test_secret-Q6dOdK",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:sts::123456789:assumed-role/ProdAdmin-Prod-Role/myUsername"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

it does not work, it still blocks me from accessing it as well.
How can I specify the principle so that aws will recognize it?
NOTE:
When I remove username after role, it works but everyone with that role can access it as well which is not the desirable effect.
I tried this
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:af-south-1:123456789:secret:test_secret-Q6dOdK",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalArn": [
            "arn:aws:sts::123456789:assumed-role/ProdAdmin-Prod-Role/myUsername",
            "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/ProdAdmin-Prod-Role"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

and it did not work, when I specify the role it makes everyone with the role have access to the key which I do not want

I recommend creating an Allow policy with StringEquals to your role arn, it will make sure by default that other users will not have access to key.

Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Consider taking the [tour].

This did not work, anyone with the role was still able to access the secret
